# How can I print Google Books api description?

Tags: symfony, twig

Hie I am trying to get the synopsis and other items like author and published date printed. But I am Able to achieve this only with certain search terms, an error occurs with other words or terms

> Key "description" for array with keys "title, subtitle, authors, publishedDate, industryIdentifiers, readingModes, pageCount, printType, categories, maturityRating, allowAnonLogging, contentVersion, imageLinks, language, previewLink, infoLink, canonicalVolumeLink" does not exist.

I am using symfony and twig. this is what the twig file looks like :

`{% for item in items %}
    <article>
    <img src="{{ item.volumeInfo.imageLinks.thumbnail}}"/>
    <h4>{{ item.volumeInfo.title}}</h4>
    {{ item.volumeInfo.description }}
    <strong> {{ item.volumeInfo.publishedDate }}</strong><br/>
    <b>{{ item.volumeInfo.authors | join }}</b>
</article>`

What am I doing wrong? why does this work only sometimes ? how can I make it work correctly all the time?

```
class GoogleBooksController extends Controller
{
public function getVolumeAction($title)
{

    $client =new client();
    $response = $client-         >get("https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=$title");
    $data=$response->json();

    $items=$data['items'];


    return $this->render('BookReviewBundle:GoogleBooks:volume.html.twig', array('items'=>$items
            // ...
        ));    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I belive the description field is not mandatory, so you can do follow

```
{% if item.volumeInfo.description is defined %}
{{ item.volumeInfo.description }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I have followed you advice but the problem persists

Comment: pls show your controller, I belive you are requesting description in some other place(s) too

Comment: after you changed to "item.volumeInfo.description is defined", did you clear the cache?

Comment: it should be ok with that check, try changing something in the twig to be sure the twig changed like deleting the item.volumeInfo.description code and see if the error still happens that means the cache is still there or this code is happening also somewhere else, if so check the cache cleared if you use prod/dev clear both to be sure